# i can't acces a filepath using pyautogui

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

Hello guys i hope you are doing well

i'm working on a python project and i'm using pyautogui library , the idea is to automate a task in my computer , i'm trying to send a pdf file via whatsapp , and to do that i have first to access the filepath but when i write
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQdYX.png)

it shows me an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZEGT.png)

i hope u guys to help me skip this problem

Comment: @ Ismail Anna you must provide source code in text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not escape and use linux like `/` instead of `\`, but youve hidden the path.

Comment: I did ,  even if i used / it shows the same message , it's like windows doesn't allow to other programms to access to files

Comment: On Windows you have to use \ and cause its a special character it needs to be escaped with another \ for instance C:\\Users\\Username\\Path\\To\\Folder

Comment: thank u mxwmnn for your help